# How do you define “independence” in combinatorics?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I feel like most definitions of “independence” are circular. Consider how we count the number of cards in a standard deck of cards: $|S \times R| = |S||R|$, where $S$ is the set of suits, and $R$ is the set of ranks. That is, $$S = \{\text{Hearts, Diamonds, Spades, Clubs}\}$$ and $$R = \{ 2,3,\dots,\text{King},\text{Ace} \}.$$ We know that $|S| = 4$ and $|R| = 13$, so $|S \times R| = |S||R| = 4 \cdot 13 = 52.$ In such an example, we define that they are independent, because they are disjoint subsets. But do we know that? In this example, it is “obvious.” What about examples where it is not obvious?

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  If you can't be sure of independence, then you can't blindly assume it.  But I doubt that this is what you are asking...do you have an example in mind?

Comment: To be clear, in the card example, we aren't "defining" anything.  We are told (or we know from experience) that there are $4$ suits and that each suit contains $13$ ranks. That's all you need to do the calculation we indicate.  If we were only told "there are some suits and each suit has some ranks" then you couldn't compute much of anything.

Comment: In general, in early combinatorics you often learn that you can multiply two things (i.e. the “number of ways to either do something, or choices for something” when they are “independent.” But what exactly does that mean?

Comment: Well, presumably the context would be something like "Our objects have a number of characteristics.  Each characteristic has a known number of options and that number is independent of all of the other options."  That is to say, if we know that that are $C_1$ options for the first characteristic, and $C_2$ for the second, then there are $C_1\times C_2$ ways to choose the first two characteristics.  And so on.

Comment: In the real world, of course, we seldom have this sort of "independence of characteristics."  If, say, we are trying to count the students in a school at a particular moment, it makes sense to count the students in each room.  However, it is highly unlikely that there are the same number of students in each room.  Thus "the room a student is in" and "the rank of a student in a given room (assuming that each student in a room is assigned a number)" are not independent.  This is the standard situtation.

Comment: Is there a precise definition for independence?

Comment: To bring the terminology in line with its more standard use in probability, two characteristics of an object are said to be independent if knowing one of the characteristics conveys no information regarding the other.  Thus knowing the suit of a card does not tell me anything at all about its rank.  To phrase it more precisely, if the two characteristics are $X,Y$ then then conditional probability $P(X=x\,|\,Y=y)$ is equal to $P(X=x)$, regardless of the choices of $x,y$.

Comment: Suppose I asked you for how many nonnegative integers less than $30$ left a remainder of $2$ when divided by $3$, and a remainder of $2$ or $4$ when divided by $5$. The number theorist would immediately tell you that the answer is $2 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 = 4$, since the remainders when dividing by $2$, $3$, and $5$ are "independent". But what exactly is going on here? Using the "independent" justification suggests that we're counting a set of the form $A \times B \times C$, that is, a set of ordered triples. Since when is a nonnegative integer less than $30$ an ordered triple?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115713/discussion-between-trivial-math-is-difficult-and-lulu).

Comment: Most of the formal definitions of "independent" you gave *are* circular. And none of them are. Well, that's what to expect of empty sets..

Comment: In your example of integers less than or equal to $30$ you can associate each such integer with an ordered triple. Let $A=\{0,1,2\}$ be the set of residues mod $3$ and let $B=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ be the set of residues mod $5$. Since $30/(3\cdot5)=2$, the pattern of residues mod $3$ and mod $5$ repeats $2$ times. Let the elements of $C=\{1,2\}$ index the sets in which the residue pattern goes through a single repetition: $1$ for the set $\{1,2,\ldots,15\}$ and $2$ for $\{16,17,\ldots,30\}$. Then each integer between $1$ and $30$ is associated with a unique member of $A\times B\times C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a structure $S$. This structure is a combination of a few Attributes, each from a certain set of possible values.

If we let $A_1,...,A_n$ be the sets of the possible values for the corresponding attributes, then we can, pretty general, define the structure $S$ as follows:

$$
S:= \{\pmatrix{x_1\\\vdots\\x_n}\in ⨉_{i=1}^n A_i\mid P\pmatrix{x_1\\\vdots\\x_n}   \}
$$

Where $P$ is a predicate, i.e. it models our constraints, on which combinations of attributes are allowed.

Our goal, as usual in combinatorics, is determining $|S|$.

We say that the structure $S$ is independent of an attribute $A_i$ is (in the combinatoric sense), if:
$$
\forall x_1\in A_1,...,x_n\in A_n,y_i\in A_i:\qquad P(x_1,...,x_i,...,x_n) = P(x_1,...,y_i,...,x_n)  
$$

Simply put this means that we don't need to look at the value of attribute $A_i$ to find out whether a specific instance of the structure is valid.
We therefore can fix a specific $x_i\in A_i$ (which exactly we choose doesn't matter), and define
$$P':  ⨉_{k=1\\i\neq i}^n A_k\to \{\text{True},\text{False}\}$$
via
$$P'(x_1,...,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},...,x_{n}) = P(x_1,...,x_{i-1},x_i,x_{i+1},...,x_{n})$$

In terms of the cardinality, this then means the following:
$$
|S| =|A_i|\cdot  |\{\pmatrix{x_1\\...\\x_{i-1}\\x_{i+1}\\...\\x_{n}}\in ⨉_{k=1\\k\neq i}^n A_k\mid P'\pmatrix{x_1\\...\\x_{i-1}\\x_{i+1}\\...\\x_{n}}   \}|
$$

As for every tuple $\pmatrix{x_1\\...\\x_{i-1}\\x_{i+1}\\...\\x_{n}}$, the structure instance $\pmatrix{x_1\\...\\x_{i-1}\\x_i\\x_{i+1}\\...\\x_{n}}$ is either valid for all choises of $x_i$, or for none of it.

To finish this, let's look at your example.
Our structure is the set of valid cards, where each card has the two attributes suit and rank.

Therefore we have $n=2$, $A_1:= \{\text{Hearts, Diamonds, Spades, Clubs}\}, A_2:=\{ 2,3,\dots,\text{King},\text{Ace} \}$. 
Since we have no restrictions on our set members of $S$ besides that we have to pick from every attribute, we have further $P(x_1,x_2)=\text{True}$.

So, our structure $S$ is in this case independent of both $A_1$ and $A_2$, and therefore we have $|S| = |A_1|\cdot |A_2|$

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title: you don't. Independence is a concept in probability theory, not in combinatorics. In your card example, there is no concept of the sets $S$ and $R$ being independent. What you can say is that, if all $52$ cards are equally likely to be chosen in some experiment, then the probability of a particular rank, say ace, is independent of a particular suit, say clubs. But if one of the cards is sticky, and hence more likely to be chosen than the others, independence is lost.

You can look up the standard definitions of independence: for events $E$ and $F$, the events are independent if $\Pr(E\cap F)=\Pr(E)\Pr(F)$, or equivalently, if $\Pr(E\vert F)=\Pr(E)$.

Also, be careful to distinguish the concepts of disjointness and independence. They are not related.

**Added:** It looks like your question is really about sets that have the structure of a Cartesian product. If $S=A\times B$ and all elements of $S$ are equally likely, then the events $X=$"first element of tuple is $x$" and $Y=$"second element of tuple is $y$" are independent in the usual probability sense. These events are the sets $X=\{(x,b)\vert b\in B\}$ and $Y=\{(a,y)\vert a\in A\}$. Now $\Pr(X\cap Y)=\Pr(\{(x,y)\})=\frac{1}{\lvert S\rvert}=\frac{1}{\lvert A\rvert\lvert B\rvert}$, while $\Pr(X)\Pr(Y)=\frac{\lvert B\rvert}{\lvert S\rvert}\frac{\lvert A\rvert}{\lvert S\rvert}=\frac{\lvert B\rvert\lvert A\rvert}{(\lvert A\rvert\lvert B\rvert)^2}=\frac{1}{\lvert A\rvert\lvert B\rvert}$, so that the first definition of independence is satrisfied. This independence holds regardless of whether $A$ and $B$ are disjoint or not. (They might even be the same set.)

Comment: Is disjointedness what is actually being referred to when independence is taught in a combinatorics course, but not talking about probability?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. Can you give an example? Either a quotation or a reference to a book or online notes would be fine. Returning to the card example, the event ace is the set $\{AS,AH,AC,AD\}$, while the event clubs is the set $\{2C,3C,4C,5C,6C,7C,8C,9C,10C,JC,QC,KC,AC\}$. These events are not disjoint since they have non-empty intersection, $\{AC\}$. They are independent since $\Pr(\text{ace }\cap\text{ clubs})=\frac{1}{52}=\frac{1}{13}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\Pr(\text{ace})\Pr(\text{clubs})$ (assuming all cards equally likely). The events clubs and hearts are disjoint; they are not independent.

Comment: I would recommend that you have a close look at Sudix's answer and consider accepting it, as it does what you asked for, whereas mine does not. It should also help answer your question in the comment above: disjointness and independence are distinct concepts. Sudix's answer says nothing about whether the sets $A_j$ overlap or not; either may happen.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another view point. Independence is a property of partitions, not of individual sets. Namely, let $S$ be a finite set, and let $\{X_1,\dots,X_m\}$ and $\{Y_1,\dots,Y_n\}$ be two partitions of $S$ (meaning the $X_i$ are nonempty, disjoint, and have a union of $S$, and same for the $Y_i$). We say that these two partitions are independent if
$$
|X_i\cap Y_j|\text{ is the same for all }i\in \{1,\dots,m\},j\in \{1,\dots,n\}
$$
For example, let $S$ be a deck of cards, and let
$$
X_1=\{\text{the set of spades}\}=\{A\spadesuit,2\spadesuit,\dots,K\spadesuit\},\\X_2=\{\text{the set of hearts}\},\\ X_3=\{\text{the set of clubs}\}\\
X_4=\{\text{the set of diamonds}\}
$$
and
$$
Y_1=\{\text{set of aces}\},Y_2=\{\text{set of twos}\},\dots,Y_{13}=\{\text{set of kings}\}
$$
Since it is true that $|X_i\cap Y_j|=1$ for all $i,j$, we conclude these two partitions are independent.

A consequence of the definition of independence is that
$$
|S|=m\cdot n\cdot |X_1\cap Y_1|
$$